# Adding elements to an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

Say that I have an empty array as follows:

```
s=[];
```

Say that for instance we have the following loop:

```
for j=1:2
   for i=1:10
      if a(i,j)>0
      ...
      end
   end
end
```

Instead of `...`, I want to add elements to `s`. How do you do that in MatLab?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you avoid loops altogether. They are slow in MATLAB.

Let's say you want to set all values in `S(i,j)` to 1 that correspond to `A(i,j) > 0`. You could do:

```
S = zeros(size(A));    % always a good idea to initialize your array
S(A > 0) = 1;          % and done.
```

More succinctly:

```
S = A > 0;
```

This specifies that you are changing the values of `S` to 1 corresponding to those values of `A` where `A > 0`.

If you want to set the value of `S` to the corresponding value of `A` then you would just use:

```
S = A(A > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of another index and just add elements as you go along:

```
idx = 1
for j=1:2
    for i=1:10
        if a(i,j)>0
            s(idx) = a(i,j)
            idx = idx + 1
        end
    end
end
```

Though for your particular problem, you could just write

```
a(a>0)
```

Comment: There's no need to keep another index.  You could just use `s(end + 1)` instead.

Comment: @KronoS that's correct, but in some cases you want to actually use that index in an expression.  For example, `s(idx) = a(i,j) + idx`.

Comment: I guess it's a personal preference but you could get away with it by using this: `s(end + 1) = a(ii, jj) + size(s, 2);` assuming it's a row array and not a column.